# Why use PUT methods?

Tags: http, post, put

There does not seem to be any advantage over using POST.  Is there a specific scenario where PUT works better/ faster/ more securely/ something else?  Why would anyone code for a whole new http method when you can do everything with basically the same amount of work using a POST?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: @AhmedMasud a good link; it seems, as I suspected, that at this point, it's much more of a preference than an advantage/ disadvantage thing.  I think I'll just be using POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM RFC2616:

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is
>   reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a
>   POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed
>   entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to
>   some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations. In
>   contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with
>   the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the
>   server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource.

Comment: A vote to close and then a copy/paste from my RFC link? Hrm.

Comment: I think Ahmed got there first.